# multipart/x-mixed-replace PNG stream always showing frame before last

Tags: javascript, http, go, multipart-mixed-replace

Having made a program which streams PNG images to the browser by means of a `multipart/x-mixed-replace` `Content-Type` header, I noticed that only the frame before-last is displayed in the `<img>` tag, as opposed to the most recently sent one.

This behaviour is very annoying, as I'm only sending updates when the image changes to save on bandwidth, which means that the wrong frame will be on screen while I'm waiting for it to update.

Specifically, I am using Brave Browser (based on chromium), but as I have tried with both "shields" up and down, I assume this problem occurs also in other chromium-based browsers at least.

Searching for the problem yields only one relevant result (and many non-relevant ones) which is [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/multipart-x-mixed-replace-not-working-i-think-its-due-to-buffering-or-caching.73496/) HowToForge thread, with no replies. Likewise, I also thought the issue is to do with buffering, but I made sure to flush the buffer to no avail, much alike to the user in the thread. The user does report that it works on one of their servers though and not the other, which then lead me to believe that it may be to do with a specific HTTP header or something along those lines. My first guess was `Content-Length` because the browser can tell when the image is complete from that, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

So essentially, my question is: **Is there a way to tell the browser to show the most recent `multipart/x-mixed-replace`** and not the one before? And, if this isn't standard behaviour, what could the cause be?

And of course, here's the relevant source code, though I imagine this is more of a general HTTP question than one to do with the code:

## Server

```
package routes

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    brain "path/to/image/generator/module"
)

func init() {
    RouteHandler{
        function: func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")
            w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache") // <- Just in case
            w.WriteHeader(200)

            // If the request contains a token and the token maps to a valid "brain", start consuming frames from
            // the brain and returning them to the client
            params := r.URL.Query()
            if val, ok := params["token"]; ok && len(val) > 0 {
                if b, ok := SharedMemory["brains"].(map[string]*brain.Brain)[val[0]]; ok && !b.CheckHasExit() {
                    // Keep a checksum of the previous frame to avoid sending frames which haven't changed. Frames cannot
                    // be compared directly (at least efficiently) as they are slices not arrays
                    previousFrameChecksum := [16]byte{}

                    for {
                        if !b.CheckHasExit() {
                            frame, err := b.GetNextFrame(SharedMemory["conf"].(map[string]interface{})["DISPLAY_COL"].(color.Color))
                            if err == nil && md5.Sum(frame) != previousFrameChecksum {
                                // Only write the frame if we succesfully read it and it's different to the previous
                                _, err = w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\nContent-Size: %d\r\n\r\n%s\r\n", len(frame), frame)))
                                if err != nil {
                                    // The client most likely disconnected, so we should end the stream. As the brain still exists, the
                                    // user can re-connect at any time
                                    return
                                }
                                // Update the checksum to this frame
                                previousFrameChecksum = md5.Sum(frame)
                                // If possible, flush the buffer to make sure the frame is sent ASAP
                                if flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
                                    flusher.Flush()
                                }
                            }
                            // Limit the framerate to reduce CPU usage
                            <-time.After(time.Duration(SharedMemory["conf"].(map[string]interface{})["FPS_LIMITER_INTERVAL"].(int)) * time.Millisecond)
                        } else {
                            // The brain has exit so there is no more we can do - we are braindead :P
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }.Register("/stream", "/stream.png")
}
```

## Client (`start()` runs in body `onload`)

```
function start() {
    // Fetch the token from local storage. If it's empty, the server will automatically create a new one
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    // Create a session with the server
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", "/startsession?token="+(token)+"&w="+(parent.innerWidth)+"&h="+(parent.innerHeight));
    http.send();
    http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
            // Save the returned token
            token = http.responseText;
            localStorage.setItem("token", token);
            // Create screen
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.alt = "main display";
            // Hide the loader when it loads
            img.onload = function() {
                var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
                loader.remove();
            }
            // Start loading
            img.src = "/stream.png?token="+token;
            // Start capturing keystrokes
            document.onkeydown = function(e) {
                // Send the keypress to the server as a command (ignore the response)
                cmdsend = new XMLHttpRequest();
                cmdsend.open("POST", "/cmd?token="+(token));
                cmdsend.send("keypress:"+e.code);
                // Catch special cases
                if (e.code === "Escape") {
                    // Clear local storage to remove leftover token
                    localStorage.clear();
                    // Remove keypress handler
                    document.onkeydown = function(e) {}
                    // Notify the user
                    alert("Session ended succesfully and the screen is inactive. You may now close this tab.");
                }
                // Cancel whatever it is the keypress normally does
                return false;
            }
            // Add screen to body
            document.getElementById("body").appendChild(img);
        } else if (http.readyState === 4) {
            alert("Error while starting the session: "+http.responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a caching issue. Make the img.src url unique by adding some random junk as a get param.

Comment: @John That crossed my mind, but the image does change, it just changes one frame too late, so it's unlikely that it's caching IMO. On top of that, the token changes between program restarts (and that's a GET param) so that somewhat stops caching, and then also I added the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header for good measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A part inside a multipart MIME message starts with the MIME header and **ends** with the boundary. There is a single boundary before the first real part. This initial boundary closes the MIME preamble.

Your code instead assumes that a part **starts** with the boundary. Based on this assumption you first send the boundary, then the MIME header and then the MIME body. Then you stop sending until the next part is ready. Because of this the end of one part will only be detected once you send the next part, since only then you send the end boundary of the previous part.

To fix this your code should initially send one boundary to end the MIME preamble. For each new part it should then send the MIME header, the MIME body and then the boundary to end this part.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, and thanks for the answer. I think I actually tried somewhat what you described before asking, but it didn't seem to work, so I put the boundary at the end to test. Anyway, what you said seems correct, but even having changed it I'm having the same issue. I've done a bit of cURL debugging, and found that when I include the boundary at the end, it does not get sent until the next request still, even being part of the same byteslice. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: I realise what I wrote may be difficult to follow, so here's the [updated code](https://pastebin.com/G5cfiruk), [cURL log](https://pastebin.com/bEE4Sh0Z) and [program log](https://pastebin.com/8Y6vGpaH) which might hopefully clarify. The issue is that even though I am now sending the `--frame` trailer, it does not actually get sent for some reason.

Comment: A further update - adding two newlines to the end (after `--frame`) solves the issue of `--frame` not being sent, but now because there are 2 newlines after `--frame`, the browser can no longer read the response.

Comment: @user9123: The boundary need to be send as `\r\n--frame\r\n`, not `\r\n--frame` as currently done, i.e. the end of line __after__ the boundary is important too. Of course the MIME header after the boundary should then just start with the first header line and not another `\r\n`.

Comment: I've updated my [code](https://pastebin.com/bTHFc471) once again, this time to use Go's standard `mime/multipart` package, so I should no longer have issues with the protocol. Still though I'm 1 frame behind (the image doens't load until I press space to trigger an update). I feel like it's to do with `flusher.Flush()` not working, but I don't know why that would be the case. Any ideas?

Comment: @user9123: Can you please provide some complete code I can easily try myself or can you provide some full packet capture (provided this is plain HTTP, not HTTPS), so that one can see what is actually going on?

Comment: of course! I didn't do that thus far only because I didn't want to seem like I expect you to go through my entire codebase and fix my bugs :) . The whole source is at https://li.an-atom-in.space/trslimey/GoPhysicsLab . It doesn't use HTTPS so you should be able to capture packets easily.

EDIT: Oops, forgot to push the recent tweaks, but they're there now.

Comment: @user9123: Thanks. Not sure how to use it though. I mean I can build and run the server and I can see the initial multipart in wireshark but how could I trigger more images? Apart from that the multipart golang packet is not really suitable for this purpose: it uses the same logic as you did first, i.e. will only write the boundary when writing the next part.

Comment: To generate more frames you can just press the space key while the tab is focused. At the moment it just colours random pixels for testing. The escape key kills the program also. As for the `multipart` lib, I'll roll back to the pre-`multipart` code in that case, if you want to keep testing. I think ultimately the problem is to do with flushing the data in that particular setup.

Comment: @user9123: Unfortunately it is impossible to know if the currently display image is the expected one based on this :( Anyway, based on a packet capture the flushing is definitely not the problem, i.e. everything expected can be seen on the wire. It might help also to add a `Content-Length` header to each part, not `Content-Size` as in your original code.

Comment: I usually just count the pixels :P also if the image is not there on page load and you have to press space for it to appear. Did that not happen in your case? if so then that's a big hint towards my environment. But yeah, having tested again with cURL, I see also now that the `--frame` part is indeed there. That's really weird because I'm certain that was not the case before, although I did switch out `w.Write` for `fmt.Fprintf` this time and used `Content-Length` as suggested - not sure if that had any effect, the frame still seems one behind.

Comment: Also, thanks for sticking around for so long. I really appreciate that :) I don't think we'll find any simple solution any time soon, so I might try to use some kind of workaround instead, but other than this weird issue, you have answered the question so I'll also be sure to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: There is 1 frame delay when using `multipart/x-mixed-replace`

This problem seems to appear in Chrome and it seems related to the fact [Chrome no longer support](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249132) `multipart/x-mixed-replace` resources. This problem is not present in Firefox.

So, the only way to "trick" Chrome into displaying a video stream is to send every image twice or accept there will be 1 frame delay.
As said, problem not present in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with Chrome. In Firefox it worked as expected.

I worked around it in the following way `C# example`

```
var chromeWorkaround = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"\r\n--{Boundary}\r\n\r\n--{Boundary}\r\n");
```

Append this to your stream and it seems to force chrome to render immediately.

I reported it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1250396

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it send image immediately without 1-frame delay with Google Chrome by sending following sequence:

```py
def frame_generator():
    image = None

    buf = BytesIO()
    buf.write(b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n")
    yield buf.getvalue()

    while True:
        image = self.get_image()
        img = Image.fromarray(image)

        buf = BytesIO()
        img.save(buf, "JPEG")
        buf.write(b"\r\n--frame\r\n")
        buf.write(b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n")
        yield buf.getvalue()
```